# Error while installing postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation, virtual-machine

I've never used postgres, only MySQL, so it's new for me.
I'm trying to installing it on a VM(so I can use only command line). Running the command `sudo apt-get install postgresql` this is my output:

> Reading package lists...Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done The following packages were automatically
>   installed and are no longer required:   adwaita-icon-theme aspell
>   aspell-en at-spi2-core dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service
>   dictionaries-common emacsen-common enchant fontconfig gedit-common
>   gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
>   gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 glib-networking
>   glib-networking-common   glib-networking-services
>   gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x gtk-update-icon-cache
>   hicolor-icon-theme   humanity-icon-theme hunspell-en-us libaa1
>   libaspell15 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
>   libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data   libavahi-common3
>   libavc1394-0 libboost-filesystem1.62.0 libboost-system1.62.0 libcaca0
>   libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcdparanoia0 libcolord2
>   libcontent-hub-glib0 libcroco3 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdconf1 libdv4
>   libegl1-mesa libenchant1c2a libepoxy0 libflac8 libgbm1
>   libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin   libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
>   libgraphite2-3 libgspell-1-1 libgspell-1-common
>   libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
>   libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0   libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
>   libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgudev-1.0-0
>   libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libhunspell-1.4-0 libhyphen0
>   libiec61883-0 libjack-jackd2-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig0
>   libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
>   liblcms2-2 libmirclient9   libmircommon7 libmircore1 libmirprotobuf3
>   libnotify4 libogg0 libopus0 liborc-0.4-0 libpango-1.0-0
>   libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
>   libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libpixman-1-0 libprotobuf-lite10
>   libproxy1v5 libraw1394-11 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common
>   libsamplerate0 libsecret-1-0   libsecret-common libshout3
>   libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspeex1 libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla
>   libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libtiff5 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0
>   libvisual-0.4-0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvpx4 libwavpack1
>   libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1-mesa
>   libwayland-server0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37   libwebp6 libxcb-render0
>   libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxkbcommon0 libyelp0
>   linux-headers-4.10.0-35 linux-headers-4.10.0-35-generic
>   linux-image-4.10.0-35-generic   linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic
>   linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic
>   notification-daemon python3-cairo python3-gi-cairo ubuntu-mono   yelp
>   yelp-xsl zenity zenity-common Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove
>   them. The following additional packages will be installed:   libpq5
>   postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-client-common
>   postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.6 sysstat Suggested packages:
>   postgresql-doc locales-all postgresql-doc-9.6 libdbd-pg-perl isag The
>   following NEW packages will be installed:   libpq5 postgresql
>   postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-client-common
>   postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.6 sysstat 0 upgraded, 8 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded. Need to get 5049 kB of
>   archives. After this operation, 20.3 MB of additional disk space will
>   be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Get:1
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libpq5
>   amd64 9.6.6-0ubuntu0.17.04 [79.8 kB] Get:2
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64
>   postgresql-client-common all 179ubuntu0.1 [28.6 kB] Get:3
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64
>   postgresql-client-9.6 amd64 9.6.6-0ubuntu0.17.04 [890 kB] Get:4
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64
>   postgresql-common all 179ubuntu0.1 [157 kB] Get:5
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64
>   postgresql-9.6 amd64 9.6.6-0ubuntu0.17.04 [3125 kB] Get:6
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64
>   postgresql all 9.6+179ubuntu0.1 [5262 B] Get:7
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64
>   postgresql-contrib-9.6 amd64 9.6.6-0ubuntu0.17.04 [492 kB] Get:8
>   http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 sysstat amd64
>   11.4.3-1 [272 kB] Fetched 5049 kB in 3s (1648 kB/s) perl: warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your locale
>   settings:     LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",  LC_ALL = (unset),   LC_TIME =
>   "it_IT.UTF-8",    LC_MONETARY = "it_IT.UTF-8",    LC_ADDRESS =
>   "it_IT.UTF-8",    LC_TELEPHONE = "it_IT.UTF-8",   LC_NAME =
>   "it_IT.UTF-8",    LC_MEASUREMENT = "it_IT.UTF-8",     LC_IDENTIFICATION =
>   "it_IT.UTF-8",    LC_NUMERIC = "it_IT.UTF-8",     LC_PAPER = "it_IT.UTF-8",
>     LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
>       are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8"). locale: Cannot set LC_ALL
>   to default locale: No such file or directory Preconfiguring packages
>   ... Selecting previously unselected package libpq5:amd64. (Reading
>   database ... 194493 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../0-libpq5_9.6.6-0ubuntu0.17.04_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking libpq5:amd64 (9.6.6-0ubuntu0.17.04) ... dpkg: unrecoverable
>   fatal error, aborting:  fork failed: Cannot allocate memory W: Could
>   not open file /var/log/apt/eipp.log.xz - open (12: Cannot allocate
>   memory) W: Could not open file '/var/log/apt/eipp.log.xz' -
>   EIPP::OrderInstall (12: Cannot allocate memory) E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

then, if I try again the output is

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

How can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Set your locale appropriately and retry, like the error message says.

Comment: i've already run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but it returns or ask nothing. it just don't do nothing

Comment: Remove and reinstall. But first make sure that your locale is installed.

Comment: In another linux machine I've a db and I manage it with pgAdminIII. Alternatively is it possible export in .sql format the db so I can import it in my VM (and manage it with MySQL)?

Comment: First you must have PostgreSQL running. And PostgreSQL has nothing to do with MySQL. Did you install the Italian locale?

Comment: I've set the locale and it works!! thank you so much!